# Jquery inside of CFDiv

Tags: coldfusion

I have a page that includes a CFDiv tag that displays content from another file.

```
 <cfajaximport tags="cfwindow,cfform,cflayout-tab,cfdiv">
 <cfoutput><cfdiv class="vehicle-log" bind="url:trip_tab.cfm?ticketid=#ticketnum#" ID="theDiv"  bindOnLoad = "true"/></cfoutput>
```

The external file has jquery tabs and jquery datepicker. None of the jquery seems to work in the CFDiv. If I call the external page by itself, everything works fine.

The reason I'm using a CFDiv here (I know most people hate cf layout stuff) is because the external page has a form element that I can submit and add to data to the db without refreshing the whole parent page. This is the only way I know how to do this.

Anyways, does anyone know how to get my jquery elements to work in a CFDiv?

Thanks. 
Brian

Comment: The F12 key should bring up a window that will enable you to see what is going on with your javascript.

Comment: _"This is the only way I know how to do this."_ - Then learn how to do it properly and you wont be crippled when it doesn't work (as is the case now). The [jQuery documentation](http://learn.jquery.com) has a whole section on performing HTTP requests with JavaScript, aka [AJAX](http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/).

Comment: I agree with @PeterBoughton the first step in solving this is removing your reliance on `<cfdiv>`. If you are refusing to do this, then it's tricky to help you. There are even instructions how not to use `<cfdiv>` on ColdFusion UI the Right Way: https://github.com/cfjedimaster/ColdFusion-UI-the-Right-Way/blob/master/chapters/cfdiv/index.md

Answer (score 2):

You've got more than one problem here.  First, you are using `<CFDiv>`, which under the covers is using portions of a very old version of ExtJS.  So you are likely going to run into some headaches with mixing ExtJS and jQuery (and jQuery plugins).

Second, since `<CFDiv bind="...">` uses AJAX to load the external HTML window content, you would need to change your JavaScript strategy.  `<CFDiv>` will not pull in and execute the JavaScript code (including jQuery) from the external page (trip_tab.cfm), unless you only use CF UI widgets inside that external page (then the `<cfajaximport>` tag handles that for you).  It only loads the HTML DOM content.  You will have to move any `<script>` and `<link rel="stylesheet">` tags and custom JavaScript/jQuery code and CSS into the parent page (the page that has the `<CFDiv>` tag in it).  Then you'll have to find a way to listen for the AJAX event (completion of loading the external page) and call the custom JavaScript/jQuery code.

As others suggested in the comments above, using `<CFDiv>` is only making things harder for you.  If you switched to using one JavaScript library for your UI components (like jQuery/jQueryUI/jQuery plugins), and put all of the necessary code into your main page, what you desire can be accomplished fairly easily.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Didn't realize I'd strike a nerve as I did. I'm just a newbie at this point and definately am willing to learn new approaches. I will check out Adams link! Thx.

Comment: From the link above, If I use the more direct method of loading content into a <div> using the .load jquery method, submitting the form element on that content refreshes the entire parent page. Is there a way to just refresh the contents of the div and not the whole page?

Comment: jQuery lets you bind/intercept [form submit events](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) - so you can replace the standard behaviour with another .load call to reload just that div.

Comment: Ok thanks. I think I'll post a seperate question pertaining specifically to form submit events to get more detailed assistance on that.

Answer (score -1):

I found a simple work around... CFdiv creates what feels like a seperate browser window, but its not actually one. So it can't pull Javascript files in via:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
```

The above is telling the browser "go fetch this file" - but since your CFdiv is not really a browser (Its a controversial permutation of CFajax as described here) it doesn't do it.

Technically,  the above makes the browser include it into the page, just as if you cfincluded it , or just pasted the Javascript in there.

So convert the above to:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><cfinclude template="/js/scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
```

And included javascript will work! (provided there aren't any conflicts with cfajax et al)

I had a similar problem in that my jquery was not working, and doing this fixed it.